# Flutter moor: Got error when adding moor file to make index

Tags: flutter, flutter-moor

I am trying to use flutter moor on my application. So after creating a column:

```
import 'package:moor_flutter/moor_flutter.dart';

@DataClassName("LocationTable")
class LocationTables extends Table {
  TextColumn get locationUuid => text()();
  RealColumn get latitude => real()();
```

Now I want to make locationUuid as index. So According it's [official site](https://moor.simonbinder.eu/docs/using-sql/moor_files/) I created a moor file to add index:

```
CREATE INDEX location_uuid_index ON LocationTables (locationUuid);
```

after that I added this file in db calss:

```
@UseMoor(include: {
  'index.moor'
}, tables: [
  UserTables,
  LocationTables,
], daos: [
  UserDao,

])
class Database extends _$Database {
```

But after run build runner:

```
pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

I got This error:

```
[WARNING] moor_generator:moor_generator on lib/database/database.dart:
line 3, column 37: Target table LocationTables could not be found.
  ╷
3 │ CREATE INDEX location_uuid_index ON LocationTables (locationUuid);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution. I put answer to help someone:

In moor file I have to write table name like this:

```
CREATE INDEX location_uuid_index ON location_tables (location_uuid);
```

and after that build runner was success.

And This added in database.g.dart:

```
abstract class _$Database extends GeneratedDatabase {
  _$Database(QueryExecutor e) : super(SqlTypeSystem.defaultInstance, e);
  $LocationTablesTable _locationTables;
  $LocationTablesTable get locationTables =>
      _locationTables ??= $LocationTablesTable(this);
  Index _locationUuidIndex;
  Index get locationUuidIndex => _locationUuidIndex ??= Index(
      'location_uuid_index',
      'CREATE INDEX location_uuid_index ON location_tables (locationUuid);');
```

Attention to :

- **location_tables**
- **location_uuid**

Comment: Hi, Is how does the 'locationUuidIndex' gets used when querying the moor table?